Installing different brands of ram on HPE ProLiant DL360 Gen9 error 239-DIMM
A couple of years ago, I purchased a used HP DL360 Gen9 server with the following specs:
CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v3 @ 3.20GHz
RAM: 128GB (4x 32GB Samsung SOUB000727361F289A 32GB 2Rx4 PC4-2400T-LAO-11-MCO)
Recently, I decided to upgrade the RAM by adding another 128GB. I bought:
RAM: 4x SK hynix 32GB 2Rx4 PC4-2400T-RB2-11 HMA84GR7AFR4N-UH TD AC
The goal was to fill the remaining white slots for the second CPU. Unfortunately, the upgrade was unsuccessful, and I kept encountering the following error:
239-DIMM Configuration Error
RDIMM and LRDIMM are installed in the system. The system cannot have both types of DIMMs installed. System Halted!
I would really appreciate it if you guys could help
239 Error
Samsung(old rams on the server)Hynix(new ones that i bought)
before adding new rams,when server is working with 4 of them

You can't mix RDIMMs and LR-DIMMs. Simple as that.

I'd say the answer is pretty obvious here. The new Hynix RAM is Load-Reduced DIMM; the older Samsung is Registered DIMM, and the timing and access requirements on the two types are different enough that the server can't do both at the same time. Either find some RDIMM to replace the Hynix, or get a second batch of Hynix stuff to replace the Samsung. And be aware that questions about obsolete hardware are almost always downvoted and closed on this area.
